# Laravel Queue with Supervisor, running but not processing jobs

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord

I have set up Laravel Queue using the database and I've configured Supervisor to keep it running, however it stops processing the queue after a while.

I'm using `Mail::queue` to send e-mails. If I SSH into the server and run `php /home/my/path/to/artisan --env=production --timeout=240 queue:listen --tries=5` then it works fine and the e-mails send. But obviously I don't want to have to SSH in to process the e-mails, I want the queue running 24/7 so I installed supervisor to manage this. I have edited my supervisord.conf file to include the following program:

```
[program:laravel_queue]
command=php /home/my/path/to/artisan --env=production --timeout=240 queue:listen --tries=5
autostart=true
autorestart=true
logfile=/var/log/laraqueue.log
```

And when I start the program it works, my e-mails send. However after some time (normally the next day) the e-mails wont send. I check the database and the jobs table is filling up. When I SSH into the server and run `supervisorctl status` I get:

```
laravel_queue  RUNNING    pid 21081, uptime 2 days, 23:18:51
```

It's saying 2 days as it's been running over the weekend and not working today (Monday). Clearly it's not running, so how do I get supervisord to recognise that it's not running and restart it?

If I manually restart it with `supervisorctl restart laravel_queue`, because it's not running supervisor can't stop it and just seems to hang until I press CTRL + C. At which point I get a traceback that I don't understand:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/supervisorctl", line 6, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/supervisor/supervisorctl.py", line 598, in main
    c.onecmd(" ".join(options.args))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/supervisor/supervisorctl.py", line 86, in onecmd
    return func(arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/supervisor/supervisorctl.py", line 467, in do_restart
    self.do_stop(arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/supervisor/supervisorctl.py", line 433, in do_stop
    result = supervisor.stopProcess(processname)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1199, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1489, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/supervisor/options.py", line 1309, in request
    errcode, errmsg, headers = h.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 1064, in getreply
    response = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 990, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 391, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 349, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py", line 433, in readline
    data = recv(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Checking the status again reports the queue as stopped, so I run `supervisorctl start laravel_queue` and I get the same hang as when running restart, but it has started as the jobs are processed and e-mails sent. If I press CTRL + C again I get the same traceback as above.

#### Log

I've checked the laraqueue log after leaving it over night. I tried to send an e-mail this morning and the job table is just sitting there waiting to process. The log is just full of this:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.10^M
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8^M
^M
```

That's it. Just lots of that being repeated.

I've checked the supervisor log and it just reports the successful start of laravel_queue. For completion the log is:

```
2015-10-21 14:25:24,997 INFO /var/tmp/supervisor.sock:Medusa (V1.1.1.1) started at Wed Oct 21 14:25:24 2015
    Hostname: <unix domain socket>
    Port:/var/tmp/supervisor.sock
2015-10-21 14:25:25,099 CRIT Running without any HTTP authentication checking
2015-10-21 14:25:25,107 INFO daemonizing the process
2015-10-21 14:25:25,108 INFO supervisord started with pid 3407
2015-10-21 14:25:25,115 INFO spawned: 'laravel_queue' with pid 3409
2015-10-21 14:25:26,729 INFO success: laravel_queue entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

### UPDATE

After updating supervisor to the latest version, I'm still having the same issue. The laraqueue.log has the same content as before, nothing useful. However the supervisor log has a little more in it this time:

```
2015-10-22 10:19:59,454 CRIT received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2015-10-22 10:19:59,454 INFO waiting for laravel_queue to die
2015-10-22 10:19:59,460 INFO stopped: laravel_queue (terminated by SIGTERM)
2015-10-22 10:19:59,460 INFO received SIGCLD indicating a child quit
2015-10-22 10:26:02,019 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2015-10-22 10:26:02,085 CRIT Server 'inet_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2015-10-22 10:26:02,092 INFO daemonizing the supervisord process
2015-10-22 10:26:02,093 INFO supervisord started with pid 17268
2015-10-22 10:26:03,105 INFO spawned: 'laravel_queue' with pid 17269
2015-10-22 10:26:04,107 INFO success: laravel_queue entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2015-10-22 10:37:22,157 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2015-10-22 10:37:22,157 INFO waiting for laravel_queue to die
2015-10-22 10:37:22,163 INFO stopped: laravel_queue (terminated by SIGTERM)
```

There was a couple instances of supervisor receiving the exit request and starting it back up, and then the end of the log is above where it stops the queue, but doesn't start it again for some reason. I've checked the laravel log (in storage/logs) but there's nothing in there for around that time.

Comment: It's clearly still running but something has happened - and an exit code hasn't been thrown for supervisor to handle. Are there any hints in your `/var/log/laraqueue.log` file?

Comment: There was another error before when using SMTP mail settings that filled the log, I've solved that problem (switched to using the local MAIL function instead). I've cleared the log out and am waiting to see if there is any errors the next time it stops. Hopefully it'll have something tomorrow.

Comment: does it work when you ssh and run `./artisan queue:listen ....` as root ? Unless you specify username, supervisor runs jobs as root, which may have side effects.

Comment: I only use root with SSH, we don't have any other account. And yes, running `php artisan queue:listen` works fine.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I'm experiencing simular issues while also running supervisor v2.1-9.

Im a bit scared to remove and install since i will probably remove the queue program written inside the conf.

Comment: @Taacoo Unfortunately not, we ended up not using the queue in the end.

Comment: You changed it into a command which you can schedule?

Comment: @Taacoo No, we just used `Mail::send` instead of `Mail::queue`

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 23):

I had same issue with Laravel 8 and supervisor 3.

I solved my problem with these commands rerun:

```
sudo supervisorctl stop all

sudo supervisorctl reread

sudo supervisorctl update

sudo supervisorctl start all
```

I hope it's help.

Comment: Thanks. I was having same issue with Laravel 8 as well but was able to get it working using your solution

Comment: Worked perfectly for CentOS 8 Laravel 8

Comment: This is a temprorary fix like restarting supervisor, it will stop again after some time.

Answer (score 8):

Check what version of Supervisor you have. Some package managers have been known to forget to update Supervisor. I think your problem will be fixed by updating Supervisor. For example v2.1 of Supervisor is from 2007 and is still in some packages.

Current version of Supervisor is v3.13 though some say (see reference at bottom) v3 is the last stable version.

Check what version of Supervisor you are using

```
[root@test supervisor]# yum list | grep supervisor
```

Compare version shown to: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/supervisor

Remove and Install (easy install is nice)

```
[root@test ~]$ yum remove supervisor
[root@test ~]$ wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python
[root@test ~]$ sudo easy_install supervisor
Searching for supervisor
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/supervisor/
Best match: supervisor 3.0
```

Update:

Please take a moment to look here, it's well worth it ( http://ahmed.amayem.com/running-a-node-js-app-ghost-in-the-background-continuously-with-supervisor-supervisord/ ). Though he is running node.js/ghost with Supervisor, I don't think that matters since this is all about Supervisor!

Refs:
https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/165

http://ahmed.amayem.com/running-a-node-js-app-ghost-in-the-background-continuously-with-supervisor-supervisord/

http://ahmed.amayem.com/woes-of-using-an-outdated-supervisord-to-run-a-node-js-app-ghost/

Comment: I was indeed running v2.1. I've installed supervisor using the commands above, do I need to do anything to get it to automatically start on reboot again?

Comment: I had to rebuild the config as there's quite a few diferences

Comment: I'll make sure it's still running tomorrow morning, and if it is I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Styphon I updated my answer. So we are at least on the right path I think. The URL I added has awesome instructions about auto reboot restart

Comment: Seems it's not solved the issue. The queue isn't processing this morning. I haven't got time to look at the logs atm, but will check them out later.

Comment: I've updated my question with the latest info, I'd appreciate it if you could take a look,

Comment: @Styphon did you happen to get this working? I have this exact issue where the queue is running but it's not processing jobs.

Comment: @Styphon I actually found a way of doing today after lots of googling that worked for me. There is a config line you can put into the worker config called "environment" and you can set environment variables there. I found my issue was that environment variables weren't being read into the app. I set them there and deploy the right worker config to the right environment and it's good to go now.

Comment: This is the best, thanks for answering. You saved my day. I was using version 3.3.5 and it didn't detect new jobs. Then I installed version 4.2.2 and it works like charm now. There are some changes to be made though.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me :

```
[program:queue-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php {project_directory}/artisan queue:work
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile= {project_directory}/worker.log
```

In my case on my ubuntu server my queue worker file is here:

> /etc/supervisor/conf.d/queue-worker.conf

Also run what @netdjw said.
Enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's old but I had exactly same problem about 2 weeks ago and I fixed it! (supervisor 3.0 here)
The problem with my queue was only one worker. When I add 2 more workers and reread/update cofig files everything works like a charm. So try to change number of workers - this may help you.

Comment: In supervisor config file (you can find them in etc/supervisor/conf.d directory ) you should change parameter "numprocs" and then run supervisorctl reread & update

Comment: Thanks for the info

Comment: @MilenaSchmidt I solved improving num of process. My question is: you know why this solution works?

Comment: @GiacomoM Glad it helped :) I'm not sure why is that working. My gues is when the one worker dies there is no other worker that helps that first one to restart. And when you have more than one that option is possible. But as I said - I'm not sure if it's true. I didn't find the answer to my problem anywhere so I just tried everything to make this work - and it finally did.

Answer (score 0):

this problems met my case, the supervisor queue process was running but not processing jobs, the problem is that you need to set an environment variable to enable it (if its already running in the background ).

```
SUPERVISE=enable
```

[image: SUPERVISE=enable]

you can check if the worker process is running by

```
ps aux | grep artisan
```